# Properties in a particular order

Tags: c#, reflection

Using reflection I have a tool that gets the properties of a class:

```
foreach (MemberInfo member in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
{
    WriteValue(streamWriter, member.Name);
}
```

Is there a way to ask "GetProperties" to return MemberInfo's in the order they are defined in the class. I seriously doubt it, but thought I'd ask.

```
class Person
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to get MemberInfo's in this order then: Id, Age

Comment: Maybe you have split a problem into an obvious and an impossible part. What do you need this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Caution:` use at your own discresion as these are obviously Microsoft's impl details, which may change in future releases]

**Update**: Mono [seems to work too](http://ideone.com/xsDugK)

I've observed consitent behaviour using MS compilers since v3.5 when I stumbled upon this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            typeof(Test).GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                .OrderBy(member => member.MetadataToken).ToList()
                .ForEach(member => Console.WriteLine(member.Name));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int SecondProperty { get; set; }
        public int FirstProperty { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, for auto-properties there isn't. You can get methods in order of declaration using debug symbols, and since property getters are methods, you can (with some work) obtain a list of properties with explicit getters (or setters) in order of declaration, but the getters of auto-properties have no source code and thus no debug symbols to indicate their location. As for CLI metadata, the compiler is not obliged to put them in order of declaration, and as reflection relies exclusively on metadata, it cannot be used for this purpose.